# Error message when using aliases with cypressIO

Tags: cypress

I get the following error message when using: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined"

I´ve done exactly as they do in the documentation: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Aliases

Can anyone see what i´m doing wrong?

```
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:4200/');
    loginPage.login();
    timeFilter.button.click();
    cy.get('#title').invoke('text').as('text');
  });

  it('should show text', () => {
    console.log(this.text);
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

Read the cypress documentation and the problem i did was using arrow functions and i did not access the alias in a closure using a .then(). As soon as i did this, it worked:

```js
cy.get('#title').invoke('text').as('text');

it('should show text', () => {
    cy.get('#main').then(function () {
      console.log(this.text);
    });
  });
```

OR use `function()` instead of `() =>` on the `it()` callback

```js
cy.get('#title').invoke('text').as('text');

it('should show text', function() {
  console.log(this.text);
});
```

Comment: You hit on the main problem - using `function()` instead of `() =>` on the `it()` callback resolves the problem, ***exactly as shown on the Cypress docs***.

Answer (score 1):

Text has always been a pain in cypress.  This could be one of a few things:

1) Sometimes `this.alias` doesn't work, try using:
`cy.get('@text').then(text => console.log(text));`

2) If the text is contained in an element below `#title`, you will have to get that specific element.  For example, `#title` might be a `div`, which contains an `h1` element inside of it, so in that case you would need to use `#title > h1` as your selector.  Post your HTML and I'll be able to tell if that's the case

3) `invoke('text')` almost never works, I'm not sure why.  I find this works much more often `cy.get('#title').then($el => el.text())`

Comment: This works, but as soon as i try to assign el.text() to a variable and access if outside the chain i get undefined. `var text;` `cy.get('#title').then($el => text = el.text())` `console.log(text)`

Comment: That's because cypress is async.  Move the code that is trying to use the `text` variable into the `.then()` block.  Either that, or set it to the `text` variable in a `before()` or `beforeEach()` block - those will complete their execution before the test starts.